# How do you share data between functions in threads with python

Tags: python, multithreading

I Have a counting function that I would like to start and restart while getting the live variables to use in another function my problem is while using threading it seams like even global variables don't seem to work to pass variables around. What I want the code to do is have a counter be triggered as needed or maybe free running I'm not sure yet. To be able to reset the counter and get the value of the counter.

Right now the counter will start and run fine but the `print_stuff` function keeps telling me that there is no attribute `countval`.

The count thread gets started at startup but I don't necessarily want it to start up immediately, I would like to trigger it as needed but I cant put `count_thread.start()` twice or it will through a error so I'm calling the thread at startup and then calling the function again to restart it as needed. Maybe there is a more elegant way of doing that.?

```
import threading
import time

def count():
    global countval
    for countval in range(3):
        print('looping')
        time.sleep(1)

def print_stuff():
    global countval
    e = input("press enter to start")
    count()
    while True:
         if countval == 3:
             print("time out")

count_thread = threading.Thread(target=count)
print_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_stuff)

print_thread.start()
count_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

`print_stuff` is getting to the `if` statement before the `count` function is able to create the variable.  Just do them in the opposite order.  Either that, or create a global `countval = 0` to start things off.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the *no attribute* problem you can use `Queue`,
and if you want to stop your counting thread you can set a global variable or you can pass a function (using `lambda` or `inner function` or ...) to do that.

Here is one way to do that:

```
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue

from typing import Callable


def count(q, stop_counting):
    # type: (Queue, Callable[[], bool]) -> None

    for countval in range(3):

        if stop_counting():
            print('stopped')
            break

        print(f'looping {countval}')
        q.put(countval)

        time.sleep(1)


def print_stuff(q):
    # type: (Queue) -> None
    while True:
        countval = q.get()

        print(f'countval gotten: {countval}')

        if countval == 3:
            print("time out")


def main():
    flag_stop_counting = False
    q = Queue()

    def stop_counting():
        return flag_stop_counting

    count_thread = threading.Thread(target=count, args=(q, stop_counting,))
    print_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_stuff, args=(q,))

    print_thread.start()
    count_thread.start()

    time.sleep(1.25)
    flag_stop_counting = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this code:

- `counter` checks if it should stop counting or not
- `counter` puts the value that it made to `q`
- `print_stuff` get the value from `q` (Note: he waits until counter puts his value in `q`)

To check that program works:

- after 1.25 seconds we change the value of `flag_stop_counting`

But if you want your counter to only have a for, i guess it's better to don't make it as a thread and run it whenever you want.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thankfor your help.  I am running into a issue I have put def print_stuff into a class with another def and if I try to call one function from another I get a ""AttributeError: 'connection' object has no attribute 'get'"  I don't understand why the function would run fine the firs time but If I call it again it gives a error. This is a link to my current code    [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828774/object-has-no-attribute-get-but-it-works-the-first-time-its-called) Thank for any help